# Pushing to state using for loop in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to push to state variable using a for loop in Angular, however, I get an error "cannot set property 'date' of undefined":

```
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  days: CalendarDay[]
  iterationDay: CalendarDay
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.generateWeekData()
    console.log(this.days)
  }

  generateWeekData() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      let whenEven = i % 2 === 0
      ;(this.iterationDay.date = new Date()),
        (this.iterationDay.quantity = 24 - i),
        (this.iterationDay.price = 13),
        (this.iterationDay.eventType = 'string'),
        (this.iterationDay.isExpenseType = whenEven),
        (this.iterationDay.isHoursEventType = whenEven),
        (this.iterationDay.isAdditionalHoursEventType = whenEven),
        (this.iterationDay.isWorkHour = whenEven),
        (this.iterationDay.isApproved = whenEven),
        (this.iterationDay.isRejected = whenEven),
        (this.iterationDay.tasksCount = 2),
        (this.iterationDay.firstTaskStart = new Date()),
        (this.iterationDay.lastTaskEnd = new Date())

      this.days.push(this.iterationDay)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Set breakpoint before push and tell us what you see?

Answer (score 1):

Foremost, you need to initialize `iterationDay` property

Something like this

```
iterationDay: CalendarDay = new CalendarDay()
```

or

```
iterationDay: CalendarDay = {};
```

based on the shape of your object.

Comment: Indeed. Plus he shouldn’t really be using a component variable for this. He’ll end up with an array of the same objects..